# Generating Ethereum Address by C/C++ (Embarcadero)

Tags: c++, windows, ethereum

I have these resources:

1- Theoretically Knowing the Procedure of creating Ethereum Address [Website](https://www.massmux.com/private-and-public-keys-on-ethereum/)

2- Pretty sure that these  function works completely right: **sha256()** and **keccak256()** by testing in [this website](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/).

3- Also knowing that this function is working properly right: **ecc_PointMultiply()** for Multiplying two strings containing hexadecimal format and returning result also in hex.

But I am stuck between my beginning point and final success :))

Please guide me, where I am doing mistake?

```
//Random hashed phrase:
AnsiString PrivateKey= sha256(Now());
AnsiString PublicKey = ecc_PointMultiply(PrivateKey, curve_G);
AnsiString ETHAddress= keccak256(PublicKey);
EthAddress=EthAddress.SubString(25, 40);//drop first 24 characters
EthAddress="0x"+EthAddress;//Not so much important yet
```

But when I enter my private key to a Web Wallet such as [MEW](https://myetherwallet.com), address that they show me, is different than what I expect to be; which gain by my SW.

Any idea when I am doing mistake?

One of my guesses is uppercase lower case of my string, if so, what to do to avoid it?

Thank you in advanced for giving me ideas and help.

C/C++ only

Windows OS Only